# Help me identify this Vintage Ganna (Italian) early 90s Bike

Tags: vintage

I just picked up this bike for little money because I need a street bike I don't care to look around and also a new project bike to work with during winter.

[image: Ganna bike early 90s]

This seems like a cool bike in my opinion but I cannot find anything on internet. It needs a ton of work but the frame condition seems quite good. I know Ganna Bike is an Italian brand, and seems to have respectable components. I would like to know which year has been built because it would be nice if we are equally old (1993), can you help to identify it better? What do you think about this bike?

[image: shimano exage 300 lx]

[image: exage biopace chainring]

[image: exage hubs]

[image: mistery front shifter]

[image: st-m050]

Comment: Nice bike!   Even if it was cheap and you don't really value it, do please still lock it.  Its pretty bad to come back to your bike and it is gone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biopace rings, splatter paint and Exage group nail it pretty firmly in the late 1980s.

It doesn't look like it's a particularly high grade frame but you may want to see if any stickers identify the tubing used. Ultimately with bikes like these, if you like how it rides, it's a great bike. I was given a 1989 bottom-tier Giant once, and it's a fairly rubbish bike, much lower components than yours, but it's also an absurd colour and is really fun to cruise around on, so it's a good bike!

Hope you enjoy yours, it seems quite well preserved.

Comment: Yep the frame is not high grade, I've a 98' Kona caldera with triple butted chromoly frame and it seems much lighter bike that this (and it has a suspension fork!). I love steel frames, there is a ton of work to do, first of all a full wheel hub rebuild since the play in the hub is huuuuuge. Hopefully the hub is not messed up and it's just the cone and ball bearings need to be replaced. Also I found funny that the rear wheel has bolts when the front quick release...

Answer (score 2):

Shimano Exage 300LX was sold from 1989-91. It'll be hard to narrow it down further than that.

That Sachs Huret thumbshifter is almost certainly a replacement part put on by a previous owner.

Comment: Damn, a little bit older than me! I know the thumbshifter is a replacement, the original one has been unmounted from the STI lever, I've to find a better replacement.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bit of history of the brand on their website here.

http://www.biciclette-ganna.it/it/storia_2.htm

Comment: I didn't know about this brand before but it has produced very nice bikes, seems like a good find.